# Opening a blender file during python script execution without changing context

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files

During execution of a python script, I'm trying to import a .blend file. It's currently not an option to load the file when Blender boots, although ideally we would get the same result either way. I'm using:

```
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=path)
```

However, this destroys bpy.context ({.window, .screen} = None), but only when blender is started without "--background". This is the relevant Blender source code (blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_files.c):

```
if (!G.background) {
    /* in background mode this makes it hard to load
    * a blend file and do anything since the screen
    * won't be set to a valid value again */
    CTX_wm_window_set(C, NULL); /* exits queues */
}
```

This causes "invalid context" problems for different operators (e.g., bpy.ops.transform.*) called afterwards.

It would be great to be able to open .blend files without the WM/GUI interference altogether. However, since there doesn't seem to be a WM-less Python call for now, restoring the original context (or at least a context equivalent to the one when Blender starts up) would also work. Bonus points for solutions without WM hacks (e.g. simulating clicks) ;-)

Comment: Do you run Blender in background mode or not?

Comment: In our live environment we do, so there it's no problem, but for developing and testing we run without --background to see what happens.

Comment: In fact, the purpose of importing a .blend file here is to import predefined objects + (Cycles) materials & lights. While everything works fine for Blender render with other file formats, .blend seems to be the only one able to export+import Cycles materials. Another way of importing Cycles-compatible scenes (without the bloated .blend file import) is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Found a WM hack based on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/how-to-cut-a-mesh-into-smaller-pieces-with-python/3623#3623) that seems to work. Some operators still complain about "PyContext 'blend_data' not found", but this doesn't seem to result in problems so far. Still feels a bit hacky though.

```
def fix_context():
    """Fix bpy.context if some command (like .blend import) changed/emptied it"""
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area, 'region': region}
                        bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)
                        break
```

Edit: this works (with --background) but only if there's running an X server for the current user. Feels like there's some gui hacking going around when Blender python scripts are running background... Running on an X-less server gives a segfault.

Comment: Background mode is actually just hiding the interface, though it is still required to hold necessary data, which is used by operators etc. I'm pretty sure you can just set `bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'` to avoid context overriding, which should slim down your code a lot.

Comment: This crashes 2.80