# divide a model into equal parts

Tags: mesh

I'm a newbie here. I have a 3d building model (with many objects when loading into blender). I want to divide the model into equal parts, for example, into eight parts (as a octree structure). 
[image]

The aim is to ease the burden of 3d visualization on web by using 3d-tiles.
(https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles)

That means I need to divide small objects (such as furniture and openings) into 8 cubes. And cut the large meshes (such as wall and floor) into 8 cubes as well.

It's a really tough work. But I wonder:

1. Is there any automatic way to divide a model into equal parts?
2. Is there any method to cut meshes into the range of a cube?

Comment: Do you want to really separate the parts into several meshes or do you just want to show only a wanted part and hide the others?

Comment: Boolean modifier of objects and arrayed cubes might do that. However note that at least tiny gap should be left between cubes as otherwise you won't be able to select individual meshes (they will be cut though)

Comment: Have a look to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/how-to-cut-a-mesh-into-smaller-pieces-with-python/3629#3629